# PaloAlto FW behind two consumer routers cannot reach internet

Tags: networking, routing, firewall, nat

I'm doing initial setup of a PaloAlto PA-440 firewall at home before I overhaul my LAN but can't get the FW to access the internet to download licenses and updates. What should I look at/change on the PA FW to get this resolved?

Here's my setup:

```
                                       [LAN1]                   [LAN2]            [LAN3]
                                       G/W:192.168.254.254/24   G/W:10.0.1.1/24   G/W:10.0.0.1/24    
Internet -> Arris cable modem (NAT) -> Synology Router (NAT) -> PA FW (NAT)    -> Mgmt IF
                                       MOCA device 1            NAS               rPi
                                       MOCA device 2            PCs
                                                                IoT
```

LAN3 Devices:

- Can ping devices on LAN2
- Can resolve DNS for internet sites
- Cannot ping devices on LAN1
- Cannot open web sites on LAN1 nor internet

LAN2 works fine and gets a ping reply from PA FW and LAN1 devices; can access internet and mgmt GUI on LAN1.

LANs 1 & 2 are consumer grade products with standard NAT & DHCP setup, including DHCP reservations for each downstream gateway. LAN3 is the PA firewall with dynamic IP & port NAT set on SOURCE. Presently, I have a broad policy there to allow all traffic from internal to external zone. Logs indicate the PA FW Rule is being matched and allowing outbound traffic but session end is either aged-out or n/a.

I'm about to start a packet capture on both LAN2 & LAN3 to see what I can find. TIA

*Caveat - I can't change the cable modem to bridge mode because of the MOCA devices, and don't want to change the Synology to bridge mode just yet because it and the NAS have custom settings that need to be ported to the PA FW... once it's updated and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that while the PA FW had the correct IP address on the outside interface, and proper zones & policies to allow outbound traffic, I overlooked that both the default static route and management interface needed updating to reflect the Synology IP address (10.0.1.1) as "next hop" and gateway, respectively.

Thanks to user @FrameHowitzer at networkengineering.stackexchange.com for pointing me in the right direction.

(Posted here for future reference.)